# How to execute open office cal (macro) in asp.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, centos7, openoffice-calc

I am developing asp.net core application that downloads some excel files and executing macro on it. 
Macro is performing some data validation and data formatting and generating new excel file. I need to save this file in a specific folder on the server.

I have hosted this application on centos 7 so obviously Microsoft interop service will not work. So, I have to execute macro using open office.

If anyone can help then it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not a place to request general help. Think about what you want to accomplish and then search the internet to see if you can find information on how to do it. If not, then ask a specific question here. Also, it is unclear to me what technologies you are asking about. Do you want to use C# or a language more commonly used with LibreOffice such as Java?

Comment: My question is how can we execute open office or libre office macro using asp.net c#.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, COM interop will not work on CentOS, so you probably want to use Java or Python instead.

However, it may work to do a [C# system call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start) and execute a Basic macro. An example from https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/150565/execute-macro-in-calc-from-terminal/:

```
soffice "macro:///Standard.Module1.Ora(2,3)" "/home/lim/Scrivania/Test.ods"
```

With this setup, much of the code will be in Basic. If you are not familiar with the language, a good place to start is http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.

Comment: Hey Jim, Can we develop API using Java or Python? So once my Excel files will be downloaded then I will call this API to execute macro.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking whether it is possible to write a Java program and then connect to it somehow from C# code on linux. A google search on this topic brought up IKVM: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/java/. Otherwise, a C# system call could run either Java or Python code.